# Injective Linear transformation .

Tags: functions, injective-module

If the linear transformation $T:\mathbb R^3\to\mathbb R^3$ defined as
$$
T(x,y,z)=(y+kz,x+ky,x-2y+z) 
$$
is injective, what is the value of $k$?

Comment: *Hints:* A linear transformation from a finite dimensional space to itself is injective iff it is bijective iff the determinant of the matrix representation of the transformation is nonzero.

Comment: TLDR: What is the determinant of $\begin{bmatrix}0&1&k\\1&k&0\\1&-2&1\end{bmatrix}$ and why does that matter?

Comment: Thanks..I can answer now..! :*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice how T is represented by the matrix \begin{bmatrix}0&1&k\\1&k&0\\1&-2&1\end{bmatrix}

Now calculating the determinant with the formula of Sarrus:

$$-2 k-k²-1=\det(T) = -(k+1)²$$

If the determinant is zero, then $T$ can't be injective. If the determinant is nonzero, then $T$ is injective.

$k$ can't be $-1$.

Comment: Check again your determinant.  You missed a constant term.

Comment: @JMoravitz Thank you, I missed a term